# onclick="parent.location='#CustomerInformation'" is working good in IE8 but not working firefox and other browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

1. GQM Order ID:
                       
                       Current Status:

   ```
                   <TD class="bold" valign="top" nowrap align="left" width="7%">
                   Customer Name:</TD>
                   <TD valign="top" nowrap align="left" width="19%"><logic:write
                       name="orderBean" property="customerLastName" />,<logic:write
                       name="orderBean" property="customerFirstName" /></TD>
                   <TD class="bold" valign="top" nowrap align="left" width="7%">
                   Shared Customer Name:</TD>
                   <TD valign="top" nowrap align="left" width="19%"><logic:write
                       name="orderBean" property="shrCustomerLastName" />,<logic:write
                       name="orderBean" property="shrCustomerFirstName" /> </TD>

               </TR>           <TR>


                   <TD class="bold" valign="top" nowrap align="left" width="7%">Customer
                   Email:</TD>
                   <TD valign="top" nowrap align="left" width="19%"><logic:write
                       name="orderBean" property="emailAddr" /></TD>
                   <TD class="bold" valign="top" nowrap align="left" width="7%">Shared Customer
                   Email:</TD>
                   <TD valign="top" nowrap align="left" width="19%"><logic:write
                       name="orderBean" property="shrEmailaddr" /></TD>            </TR>           <TR>

                   <TD class="bold" valign="top" nowrap align="left" width="12%">Phone
                   Number:</TD>
                   <TD valign="top" nowrap align="left" width="13%"><logic:write
                       name="orderBean" property="phone" /></TD>
                   <TD class="bold" valign="top" nowrap align="left" width="12%">Shared Phone
                   Number:</TD>
                   <TD valign="top" nowrap align="left" width="13%"><logic:write
                       name="orderBean" property="shrPhone" /></TD>            </TR>       </TBODY>    </TABLE>    </DIV> <DIV align="center">     <TABLE
   class="PatientBar" height="18" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
           width="98%" border="0">         <TBODY>             <TR><TD>&nbsp;</TD>             </TR>
           </TBODY>    </TABLE>    </DIV>  <DIV align="center">    <TABLE
   class="PatientBar" height="18" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
           width="98%" border="0">         <TBODY>
                <TR>
                   <TD class="bold" valign="top" nowrap align="left" width="14%"></TD>
                   <TD valign="top" nowrap align="left" width="12%"></TD>
                   <TD class="bold" valign="top" nowrap align="left" width="14%"></TD>
                   <TD valign="top" nowrap align="left" width="12%"></TD>
                   <TD class="bold" valign="top" nowrap align="left" width="12%">NPT Order:</TD>
                   <TD valign="top" nowrap align="left" width="19%"><logic:write
                       name="orderBean" property="nptInd" /></TD>          </TR>               <TR>
                   <TD class="bold" valign="top" nowrap align="left" width="14%">Affiliate:</TD>
                   <TD valign="top" nowrap align="left" width="12%"><logic:write
                       name="orderBean" property="affiliate" /></TD>
                   <TD class="bold" valign="top" nowrap align="left" width="14%">Affiliate
                   Order ID:</TD>
                   <TD valign="top" nowrap align="left" width="12%"><logic:write
                       name="orderBean" property="vendorOrderId" /></TD>
                   <TD class="bold" valign="top" nowrap align="left" width="12%">Fulfillment
                   Type:</TD>
                   <TD valign="top" nowrap align="left" width="19%"><logic:write
                       name="orderBean" property="fulfillmentTypeDesc" /></TD>             </TR>           <TR>
                   <TD class="bold" valign="top" nowrap align="left" width="18%">Order
                   Placed Date/Time:</TD>
                   <TD valign="top" nowrap align="left" width="16%"><logic:write
                       name="orderBean" property="orderPlacedDttm"
                       format="MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a" /></TD>

                   <TD class="bold" valign="top" nowrap align="left" width="18%">Promise
                   Date/Time:</TD>
                   <TD valign="top" nowrap align="left" width="16%"><logic:write
                       name="orderBean" property="promisedDttm" format="MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a"
                       nullValue="<%=WAConstants.NULL_VALUE_DATE%>" /></TD>
                   <TD class="bold" valign="top" nowrap align="left" width="18%">Store
                   Number:</TD>
                   <TD valign="top" nowrap align="left" width="19%"><logic:write
                       name="orderBean" property="storeNbr"
                       nullValue="<%=WAConstants.NULL_VALUE_NA%>" /></TD>          </TR>
               <TR>

                       <TD class="bold" valign="top" nowrap align="left">
                           Pay Type:
                       </TD>
                       <TD valign="top" nowrap align="left">
                           <logic:write name="orderBean" property="payType" nullValue="<%=WAConstants.NULL_VALUE_NA%>" />
                       </TD>


                       <TD class="bold" valign="top" nowrap align="left">
                           Pod Location:
                       </TD>
                       <TD valign="top" nowrap align="left">
                           <logic:write name="orderBean" property="podLocation" nullValue="<%=WAConstants.NULL_VALUE_NA%>" />
                       </TD>
                       <TD class="bold" valign="top" nowrap align="left">
                           Envelope Id:
                       </TD>
                       <TD valign="top" nowrap align="left">
                           <logic:write name="orderBean" property="envelopeId" nullValue="<%=WAConstants.NULL_VALUE_NA%>" />
                       </TD>
                               </TR>       </TBODY>    </TABLE>    </DIV>

       <table>         <TBODY>             <tr>
                   <td height="1"></td>            </tr>       </TBODY>    </table>

       <logic:notEmpty name="orderBean">       <table class="TheBox"
   cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">             <TBODY>
                   <tr>
                       <td><wa:permission
                           functionName="<%=WARequestFunctionName.DIGITALPHOTOGQM_ORDER_READ%>">
                           <input type="button" value="Refresh" class="buttonBig"
                               onmouseover="onMouseOverButton(this)"
                               onmouseout="onMouseOutButton(this)" onclick="onClickRefresh()">
                       </wa:permission> <logic:equal name="orderBean"
                           property="fulfillmentTypeCd"
                           value="<%=CodesDecodes.FULFILLMENT_TYPE_STORE%>">
                           <logic:notEqual name="orderBean" property="statusCd"
                               value="<%=CodesDecodes.ORDER_STATUS_CANCELLED%>">
                               <logic:notEqual name="orderBean" property="statusCd"
                                   value="<%=CodesDecodes.ORDER_STATUS_SOLD%>">
                                   <wa:permission
                                       functionName="<%=WARequestFunctionName.DIGITALPHOTOGQM_ORDER_CANCEL%>">
                                       <INPUT type="button" value="Cancel Order" class="buttonBig"
                                           onmouseover="onMouseOverButton(this)"
                                           onmouseout="onMouseOutButton(this)" name="Cancel Order"
                                           onclick="onClickCancel()">
                                   </wa:permission>
                               </logic:notEqual>
                           </logic:notEqual>                       
                           <% 
                           if((String)session.getAttribute("isMobileVendor")=="true"){ %>

                           <wa:permission
                               functionName="<%=WARequestFunctionName.DIGITALPHOTOGQM_ORDER_RESEND%>">
                               <INPUT type="button" value="Resend Mobile Order" class="buttonSuper"
                                   onmouseover="onMouseOverButton(this)"
                                   onmouseout="onMouseOutButton(this)" name="Resend Order" id = "Resend Order"
                                   onclick="onClickResendMobile()">
                           </wa:permission>

                           <% } else{%> 

                           <wa:permission
                               functionName="<%=WARequestFunctionName.DIGITALPHOTOGQM_ORDER_RESEND%>">
                               <INPUT type="button" value="Resend Order" class="buttonBig"
                                   onmouseover="onMouseOverButton(this)"
                                   onmouseout="onMouseOutButton(this)" name="Resend Order" id = "Resend Order"
                                   onclick="onClickResend()">
                           </wa:permission>

                           <%}%>

                           <wa:permission
                               functionName="<%=WARequestFunctionName.DIGITALPHOTOGQM_ORDER_RESEND%>">
                               <INPUT type="button" value="Resend Status" class="buttonBig"
                                   onmouseover="onMouseOverButton(this)"
                                   onmouseout="onMouseOutButton(this)" name="Resend Status"
                                   onclick="onClickResendStatus()">
                           </wa:permission>

                       </logic:equal> <wa:permission
                           functionName="<%=WARequestFunctionName.DIGITALPHOTOGQM_ORDER_ERROR_DETAIL_READ%>">
                           <INPUT type="button" value="Error Details" class="buttonBig"
                               onmouseover="onMouseOverButton(this)"
                               onmouseout="onMouseOutButton(this)"
                               onclick="onClickErrorDetail()">
                       </wa:permission>
                       <wa:permission
                           functionName="<%=WARequestFunctionName.DIGITALPHOTOGQM_ORDER_READ%>">
                           <INPUT type="button" value="Order Details" class="buttonBig"
                               onmouseover="onMouseOverButton(this)"
                               onmouseout="onMouseOutButton(this)" name="orderDetails" 
                               onclick="onClickRefresh()">
                       </wa:permission> <INPUT type="button" value="Customer Details"
                           class="buttonSuper" onmouseover="onMouseOverButton(this)"
                           onmouseout="onMouseOutButton(this)" name="customerDetails"
                           style="" onclick="parent.location='#CustomerInformation'"> <INPUT
                           type="button" value="Status Details" class="buttonBig"
                           onmouseover="onMouseOverButton(this)"
                           onmouseout="onMouseOutButton(this)" name="statusDetails" 
                           onclick="parent.location='#StatusInformation'"> <INPUT
                           type="button" value="Refund Details" class="buttonBig"
                           onmouseover="onMouseOverButton(this)"
                           onmouseout="onMouseOutButton(this)" name="refundDetails01" 
                           onclick="parent.location='#RefundInformation'">


                       <input type="button" value="View Order URL's" class="buttonSuper"
                       onmouseover="onMouseOverButton(this)"
                       onmouseout="onMouseOutButton(this)" onclick="showOrderUrls();">


                           </td>
                   </tr>           </TBODY>        </table>    </logic:notEmpty>

       <table>         <TBODY>             <tr>
                   <td height="1"></td>            </tr>       </TBODY>    </table>

       <div id="mainContent" style="overflow: auto; width: auto; height:
   auto">  <div class="error" id="errorText" style="display:
   none">&nbsp;&nbsp;This  is where the error goes. Way to go on
   generating an error.</div>  <table class="SectionHeader1"
   id="tableAddress">      <TBODY>             <tr>
                   <td>Order Information</td>          </tr>       </TBODY>    </table>

       <table>         <TBODY>             <tr>
                   <td height="1"></td>            </tr>       </TBODY>    </table>

       <table class="TheBox">      <TBODY>             <tr>
                   <td>
                   <DIV align="right">
                   <TABLE border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="96%"
                       id="custInfoTable" class="BoxedIn" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                       <TBODY>
                           <TR>
                               <TH align="left" width="15%">WAG Customer Number:</TH>
                               <TH align="left" width="17%">Affiliate Customer ID:</TH>
                               <TH align="left" width="17%">Campaign ID:</TH>
                               <TH align="left" width="16%">PC+ Order ID:</TH>
                               <TH align="left" height="32" width="15%">Order Type:</TH>
                           </TR>
                           <TR class="onRow" id="custInfoTableR1">
                               <TD align="left" height="34" width="137"><logic:write
                                   name="orderBean" property="walgreensCustomerId"
                                   nullValue="<%=WAConstants.NULL_VALUE_NA%>" /></TD>
                               <TD align="left" height="34" width="163"><logic:write
                                   name="orderBean" property="vendorCustomerId" /></TD>
                               <TD align="left" height="34" width="155"><logic:write
                                   name="orderBean" property="campaignIdDesc"
                                   nullValue="<%=WAConstants.NULL_VALUE_NA%>" /></TD>
                               <TD align="left" height="34" width="147"><logic:write
                                   name="orderBean" property="pcpOrderId"
                                   nullValue="<%=WAConstants.NULL_VALUE_NA%>" /></TD>
                               <TD align="left" width="137"><logic:write name="orderBean"
                                   property="orderTypeDesc" /></TD>
                           </TR>
                           <TR class="onRow">
                               <TH align="left" height="32" width="17%">Last Four Digits of
                               Credit Card:</TH>
                               <TH align="left" height="32" width="17%">Credit Card Expiration
                               (MM/YY):</TH>
                               <TH align="left" height="32" width="16%">Shipping Method:</TH>
                               <TH align="left" height="32" width="169">Carrier:</TH>
                               <TH align="left" height="32" width="169">Tracking Number:</TH>


                           </TR>
                           <TR class="onRow">
                               <TD align="left" width="163"><logic:write name="orderBean"
                                   property="creditCardNbrL4c"
                                   nullValue="<%=WAConstants.NULL_VALUE_NA%>" /></TD>
                               <TD align="left" width="155"><logic:write name="orderBean"
                                   property="creditCardExpiration"
                                   nullValue="<%=WAConstants.NULL_VALUE_NA%>" /></TD>
                               <TD align="left" width="147"><logic:write name="orderBean"
                                   property="shipToMethodDesc"
                                   nullValue="<%=WAConstants.NULL_VALUE_NA%>" /></TD>
                               <TD align="left" width="169"><logic:write name="orderBean"
                                   property="carrierDesc"
                                   nullValue="<%=WAConstants.NULL_VALUE_NA%>" /></TD>
                               <TD align="left" width="169"><logic:write name="orderBean"
                                   property="trackingNbr"
                                   nullValue="<%=WAConstants.NULL_VALUE_NA%>" /></TD>


                           </TR>
                           <TR class="onRow" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                               <TH align="left" width="15%">Created By:</TH>
                               <TH align="left" width="17%">Create Date/Time:</TH>
                               <TH align="left" width="17%">Last Updated By:</TH>
                               <TH align="left" width="16%">Update Date/Time:</TH>
                               <TD align="left" bgcolor="#ffffff"></TD>
                           </TR>
                           <TR class="onRow" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                               <TD align="left" height="17" width="137"><logic:write
                                   name="orderBean" property="createUserId" /></TD>
                               <TD align="left" height="17" width="163"><logic:write
                                   name="orderBean" property="createDttm"
                                   format="MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a" /></TD>
                               <TD align="left" height="17" width="155"><logic:write
                                   name="orderBean" property="updateUserId"
                                   nullValue="<%=WAConstants.NULL_VALUE_NA%>" /></TD>
                               <TD align="left" height="17" width="147"><logic:write
                                   name="orderBean" property="updateDttm"
                                   format="MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a"
                                   nullValue="<%=WAConstants.NULL_VALUE_DATE%>" /></TD>
                               <TD align="left" height="17" bgcolor="#ffffff"></TD>
                           </TR>
                       </TBODY>
                   </TABLE>
                   </DIV>
                   </td>           </tr>       </TBODY>    </table>

       <TABLE class="TheBox" align="center">       <TBODY>             <tr>
                   <td>
                   <fieldset><legend>Order Items</legend> <logic:define
                       id="orderItemList" name="orderBean" property="orderItemList"
                       scope="session" /> <wa:dbgrid id="orderItemGrid"
                       listBean="orderItemList" cssClass="BoxedIn" indice="i">
                       <wa:textcolumn dataField="gqmProductId"
                           headerText="GQM Product ID:" sortable="false" HAlign="left"
                           width="13%" />
                       <wa:textcolumn dataField="productDesc"
                           headerText="Product Description:" sortable="false" HAlign="left"
                           width="13%" />
                       <wa:textcolumn dataField="productQty"
                           headerText="Product Quantity:" sortable="false" HAlign="left"
                           width="8%" />
                       <wa:textcolumn dataField="unitPrice" headerText="Unit Price:"
                           sortable="false" HAlign="left" width="8%" dataFormat="$#,##0.00#" />
                       <wa:textcolumn dataField="productPriceBeforeDiscount"
                           headerText="Total Price before discount:" sortable="false"
                           HAlign="left" width="13%" dataFormat="$#,##0.00#" />
                       <wa:textcolumn dataField="productDiscountTotal"
                           headerText="Total Discount:" sortable="false" HAlign="left"
                           width="13%" dataFormat="$#,##0.00#" />
                       <wa:textcolumn dataField="productTotal" headerText="Item Total:"
                           sortable="false" HAlign="left" width="13%" dataFormat="$#,##0.00#" />
                   </wa:dbgrid>
                   <table>
                       <TBODY>
                           <tr>
                               <td height="1"></td>
                           </tr>
                       </TBODY>
                   </table>

                   <TABLE id="referralTable" class="BoxedIn" align="left">
                       <TBODY>
                           <TR class="onRow" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                               <TD align="left" width="13%" bgcolor="#ffffff" height="40"></TD>
                               <TD align="left" width="13%" bgcolor="#ffffff" height="21"></TD>
                               <TD align="left" width="8%" bgcolor="#ffffff" height="21"></TD>
                               <TD align="left" width="8%" bgcolor="#ffffff" height="21"></TD>
                               <TD bgcolor="#ffffff" class="bold" height="21" width="13%"></TD>
                               <TD bgcolor="#ffffff" class="bold" height="21" width="13%">Sub
                               Total Price:</TD>
                               <TD bgcolor="#ffffff" height="21" width="13%"><logic:write
                                   name="orderBean" property="subTotalPrice" format="$#,##0.00#" /></TD>

                           </TR>

                           <TR class="onRow" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                               <TD align="left" width="13%" bgcolor="#ffffff" height="40"></TD>
                               <TD align="left" width="13%" bgcolor="#ffffff" height="21"></TD>
                               <TD align="left" width="8%" bgcolor="#ffffff" height="21"></TD>
                               <TD align="left" width="8%" bgcolor="#ffffff" height="21"></TD>
                               <TD bgcolor="#ffffff" class="bold" height="21" width="13%"></TD>
                               <TD bgcolor="#ffffff" class="bold" width="13%">Total Order
                               Discount:</TD>
                               <TD bgcolor="#ffffff" width="13%"><logic:write name="orderBean"
                                   property="totalOrderDiscount" format="$#,##0.00#"
                                   nullValue="<%=WAConstants.NULL_VALUE_MONEY%>" /></TD>

                           </TR>
                           <TR class="onRow" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                               <TD align="left" width="13%" bgcolor="#ffffff" height="40"></TD>
                               <TD align="left" width="13%" bgcolor="#ffffff" height="21"></TD>
                               <TD align="left" width="8%" bgcolor="#ffffff" height="21"></TD>
                               <TD align="left" width="8%" bgcolor="#ffffff" height="21"></TD>
                               <TD bgcolor="#ffffff" class="bold" height="21" width="13%"></TD>
                               <TD bgcolor="#ffffff" class="bold" width="13%">Order Freight:</TD>
                               <TD bgcolor="#ffffff" width="13%"><logic:write name="orderBean"
                                   property="orderFreight" format="$#,##0.00#"
                                   nullValue="<%=WAConstants.NULL_VALUE_MONEY%>" /></TD>

                           </TR>
                           <TR class="onRow" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                               <TD align="left" width="13%" bgcolor="#ffffff" height="40"></TD>
                               <TD align="left" width="13%" bgcolor="#ffffff" height="21"></TD>
                               <TD align="left" width="8%" bgcolor="#ffffff" height="21"></TD>
                               <TD align="left" width="8%" bgcolor="#ffffff" height="21"></TD>
                               <TD bgcolor="#ffffff" class="bold" height="21" width="13%"></TD>
                               <TD bgcolor="#ffffff" class="bold" width="13%">Order Tax:</TD>
                               <TD bgcolor="#ffffff" width="13%"><logic:write name="orderBean"
                                   property="orderTax" format="$#,##0.00#"
                                   nullValue="<%=WAConstants.NULL_VALUE_MONEY%>" /></TD>

                           </TR>
                           <TR class="onRow" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                               <TD align="left" width="13%" bgcolor="#ffffff" height="40"></TD>
                               <TD align="left" width="13%" bgcolor="#ffffff" height="21"></TD>
                               <TD align="left" width="8%" bgcolor="#ffffff" height="21"></TD>
                               <TD align="left" width="8%" bgcolor="#ffffff" height="21"></TD>
                               <TD bgcolor="#ffffff" class="bold" height="21" width="13%"></TD>
                               <TD bgcolor="#ffffff" class="bold" width="13%">Order Total:</TD>
                               <TD bgcolor="#ffffff" width="13%"><logic:write name="orderBean"
                                   property="orderTotal" format="$#,##0.00#"
                                   nullValue="<%=WAConstants.NULL_VALUE_MONEY%>" /></TD>
                           </TR>
                       </TBODY>
                   </TABLE>

                   </fieldset>
                   </td>           </tr>       </TBODY>    </TABLE>

       <table class="TheBox" align="center">       <TBODY>             <tr>
                   <td>
                   <fieldset><legend>Order Promotions&nbsp; </legend>
                   <div align="center"><logic:define id="orderPromotionList"
                       name="orderBean" property="orderPromotionList" scope="session" />
                   <wa:dbgrid id="orderPromotionGrid" listBean="orderPromotionList"
                       cssClass="BoxedIn" indice="i">
                       <wa:textcolumn dataField="pluNbr" headerText="PLU Number:"
                           sortable="false" HAlign="left" width="13%" />
                       <wa:textcolumn dataField="pluDesc" headerText="PLU Description:"
                           sortable="false" HAlign="left" width="13%" />
                       <wa:textcolumn dataField="qtyApplied"
                           headerText="Quantity Applied:" sortable="false" HAlign="left"
                           width="13%" nullValue="<%=WAConstants.NULL_VALUE_NA%>" />
                       <wa:textcolumn dataField="TotalDiscount"
                           headerText="Total Discount:" sortable="false" HAlign="left"
                           width="13%" dataFormat="$#,##0.00#" />
                   </wa:dbgrid></div>
                   </fieldset>
                   </td>           </tr>       </TBODY>    </table>


       <A NAME="CustomerInformation"></A>  <table class="SectionHeader1">
           <TBODY>             <tr>
                   <td>Customer Information</td>           </tr>       </TBODY>    </table>

       <TABLE class="TheBox" align="center">

           <logic:define id="orderAddressBeanBilling" name="orderBean"
               property="orderAddressBeanBilling" scope="session" />
           <logic:define id="orderAddressBeanShipping" name="orderBean"
               property="orderAddressBeanShipping" scope="session" />

           <TBODY>             <TR>
                   <TD>
                   <FIELDSET><LEGEND>Customer Address</LEGEND>
                   <DIV align="center">
                   <TABLE id="table5" class="BoxedIn">
                       <TBODY>
                           <TR>
                               <TH colspan="3" width="50%">Billing Address</TH>
                               <TH colspan="5" width="50%">Shipping Address</TH>
                           </TR>
                           <TR class="onRow" id="table5R1">
                               <TD align="left" height="29" colspan="3" width="473">
                               <DIV id="table5R1E2"><logic:notEmpty
                                   name="orderAddressBeanBilling">
                                   <logic:write name="orderAddressBeanBilling" property="lastName" />
                                   <logic:write name="orderAddressBeanBilling" property="firstName" />
                               </logic:notEmpty></DIV>

                               <DIV id="table5R1E2"><logic:notEmpty
                                   name="orderAddressBeanBilling">
                                   <logic:write name="orderAddressBeanBilling"
                                       property="streetAddr" />
                               </logic:notEmpty></DIV>
                               <logic:notEmpty name="orderAddressBeanBilling">
                                   <logic:write name="orderAddressBeanBilling" property="city" />, <logic:write
                                       name="orderAddressBeanBilling" property="state" />
                                   <logic:write name="orderAddressBeanBilling" property="zipCode" />
                               </logic:notEmpty>
                               <DIV id="table5R2E2"><logic:notEmpty
                                   name="orderAddressBeanBilling">
                                   <logic:write name="orderAddressBeanBilling" property="countryCd" />
                               </logic:notEmpty></DIV>
                               </TD>
                               <TD align="left" height="29" colspan="5" width="469">
                               <DIV id="table5R1E20"><logic:notEmpty
                                   name="orderAddressBeanShipping">
                                   <logic:write name="orderAddressBeanShipping" property="lastName" />
                                   <logic:write name="orderAddressBeanShipping"
                                       property="firstName" />
                               </logic:notEmpty></DIV>

                               <DIV id="table5R1E20"><logic:notEmpty
                                   name="orderAddressBeanShipping">
                                   <logic:write name="orderAddressBeanShipping"
                                       property="streetAddr" />
                               </logic:notEmpty></DIV>
                               <logic:notEmpty name="orderAddressBeanShipping">
                                   <logic:write name="orderAddressBeanShipping" property="city" />, <logic:write
                                       name="orderAddressBeanShipping" property="state" />
                                   <logic:write name="orderAddressBeanShipping" property="zipCode" />
                               </logic:notEmpty>
                               <DIV id="table5R2E21"><logic:notEmpty
                                   name="orderAddressBeanShipping">
                                   <logic:write name="orderAddressBeanShipping"
                                       property="countryCd" />
                               </logic:notEmpty></DIV>
                               </TD>
                           </TR>
                       </TBODY>
                   </TABLE>
                   </DIV>
                   </FIELDSET>
                   </TD>           </TR>       </TBODY>    </TABLE>
   ```

   I tried like window.location,document.location, any many way..bt dnt
       know what is error.The '#CustomerInformation' denotes the point
       where this script will jump to same page but it is not working
       firefox.

Comment: Code dumps are not questions. Please track down the issue, and post only the relevant part of code.

Comment: @A.Wolff check out question history :-)

Comment: sry it is not IE6 ... it is IE8

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<a href="#CustomerInformation"><button>Customer Details</button></a>
```

Its silly to involve Javascript in something this simple.

As Pointy points out, it may not really be valid. But its better than what you're doing.

Really, it should be

```
<a href="#CustomerInformation">Customer Details</a>
```

Comment: It's not valid to put a button inside an `<a>` element.

Comment: Its not valid to use parent.location either. One invalid alternative that works for an invalid one that doesn't. Otherwise he's going to ask the same question 3 or 4 more times.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `parent.location` if indeed the page is in an `<iframe>`; if not then yes that would be a problem :) Anyway in the markup that `<a>` tag is not in the same place as the button; it seems that the intention is to get the browser to scroll back up.

Comment: I cant use  like <a href="#CustomerInformation">Customer Details</a> like bcz of my jsp design ...onclick="parent.location='#CustomerInformation'">  this line is culprit.When onclick it close the current page and goes to main menu instead of jump to CustomerInformation section of same jsp page.